# Where did ERROR at line 2: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis here come from?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Film_Language (
    Film_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Film(Film_Id),
    Language_Name varchar2(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Language(Language_Name),
    CONSTRAINT pk_filmlang PRIMARY KEY(Film_Id,Language_Name)
);
```

Comment: You dont need the `foreign key` here : `Film_Id int REFERENCES Film(Film_Id),` (similar for Language_Name)

Comment: ...or the datatype. If you leave that out, it'll inherit from the parent, which is generally preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Film_Language (
    Film_Id int,
    Language_Name varchar2(10),
    constraint Film_Language_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(Film_Id) REFERENCES Film(Film_Id),
    constraint Film_Language_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(Language_Name) REFERENCES Language(Language_Name),
    CONSTRAINT pk_filmlang PRIMARY KEY(Film_Id,Language_Name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `FOREIGN KEY` here:

```
Film_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Film(Film_Id)
```

, (similar for `Language_Name` ), just `REFERENCES(...)` is enough:

---

```
CREATE TABLE Film_Language (
    Film_Id int  REFERENCES Film(Film_Id)
    , Language_Name varchar2(10) REFERENCES Language(Language_Name)
    , CONSTRAINT pk_filmlang PRIMARY KEY(Film_Id,Language_Name)
);
```